# Is it possible to find the list of all apps pushed via TestFlight

Tags: iphone, testflight

I am installing AppA from CompanyA in my iPhone via TestFlight.
I am installing AppB from CompanyB in my iPhone via TestFlight.

I have my iPhone UDID to CompanyA, CompanyB. Would it be possible for CompanyA that CompanyB's app is installed in the device or vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

Well if both the Company are using different TestFlight account (which is obvious) they cannot get the data.

In TestFlight, you create teams and add Apps to that.
If the team member has developer or leader role he can have access to

```
Upload and distribute a build to a team
Delete apps and builds
Invite or recruit members to a team
View SDK data associated with a build 
Promote/demote testers/developers 
Access the team developer site on TestFlight
Respond to feedback via the developer site
Access analytics for live applications
```

At testflight website Dashboard the data is present

```
User Device Last install Update Status
```

Please note the Device UDID has to added while building the app.
Other than the dashboard no one can have the information of which users have installed the apps.

So if both company are using different TestFlight accounts and they are not having a common team member with developer or leader Role, your installation information is safe.

Dashboard information image:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. Company A will not get any information about Company B's app on your device. Any information that is private to you will not be accessible to any third party.

Answer (score 0):

no one can see which apps you are accessing in  u r phone even it is companyA or companyB that udid will be use full only to install apps when they are developing. no one can track your phone with UDID.